# make copy of file and place in new directory using relative path

Tags: filenames, cp

i have been stuck on this question for my lab for linux class

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please [edit] your question to (1) replace the screenshot with text and (2) tell us what you tried.

Comment: There are a couple of steps that come before #2: do some research (starting with a review of what you were taught in class) and then try to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an assignment I'm not going to give you the answer.  But I will point out that every directory has two special directory links:

- `.` (dot):  "This directory"
- `..` (dot-dot): "The directory above"

Answer (score 2):

First: try to write the answer using absolute path, e.g.

```
cp /path/to/file.xyz /path/to/the/target/file.xyz
```

Second: in each directory you can find

`.` = this directory

`..` = parent directory

Third: rewrite the former command using the `.` and `..` dirs. Assuming the current dir is `/path/to/` we can write:

```
cp ./file.xyz ../the/target/
```